# Spark Scala compiler not complaining about double vs. triple equals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get a compiler error if I try this

```
df.filter($"foo" == lit(0))
```

forgetting that I need a triple equals in Spark.

However, if I do this, I get the wrong answer but no error:

```
df.filter($"foo".between(baz, quux) || $"foo" == lit(0))
```

Can someone explain why compile-time checks help me in the first case, but not the second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$"foo" == lit(0)` is always evaluated as `Boolean = false`.

So in the first case, you trying to call method `filter` by passing a Boolean whereas it expects a string expression or column expression. Thus you get an error.

Now in the second, case:

`$"foo".between(baz, quux) || $"foo" == lit(0)` is evaluated as:

```sql
(((foo >= baz) AND (foo <= quux)) OR false)
```

which is accepted beacause you doing an OR `||` between a column expression (`$"foo".between(baz, quux)`) and a literal boolean `false`.

In other words, it is interpreted as `$"foo".between(baz, quux) || lit(false)`